# compile opencv 3 on ubuntu 16.04 linking error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel@GOMP_4.0'

Tags: compiler-errors, ubuntu-16.04, opencv3.1

Trying to install openCV 3.1, CUDA 8.0.44 on Ubuntu 16.04 by building from the source.

The following are the errors I met during the compilation.

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_video
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/test_optflowpyrlk.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/test_accum.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/test_kalman.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/test_ecc.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/test_tvl1optflow.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/test_camshift.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/ocl/test_optflowpyrlk.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/ocl/test_optflow_farneback.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/ocl/test_bgfg_mog2.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/ocl/test_optflow_tvl1flow.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/test/test_estimaterigid.cpp.o
[ 38%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_video
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel@GOMP_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/build.make:391: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_test_video' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_video] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3336: recipe for target 'modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_video.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I consider the issue is related to the openMP or the ld configuration.

The following are the detailed configuration:

1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

`/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib`

2. GCC version: 5.4.0
3. CMake configuration command:

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly, I thought this problem was caused because I installed Anaconda and put it into my `PATH`.

Different GCC version are used between Anaconda and System default. For Ubuntu 16.04, the GCC version is 5.4.0 however Anaconda only provides GCC 4 (I can't remember it's 4.4 or 4.8). Although I used the system default gcc to compile opencv, it somehow will find the lib located in Anaconda, which caused the problem.

I think there are two ways to solve this issue.

1. Method 1: Pass the option `-D WITH_OPENMP=ON`, or, when using cmake-gui, check the choice `WITH-OPENMP`.
2. Method 2: Delete Anaconda from your `$PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: This helped. Thanks!

Comment: This also worked for me, thank you for taking the trouble of posting your solution. Note that when using the command line, `-D WITH_OPENMP=ON` is the equivalent option that does the trick.

Comment: Passing the option '-D WITH_OPENMP=ON' also worked for me. I was using CUDA 9.1.85-1 on Ubuntu 16.04(GCC 5.4.0) attempting to build opencv 3.4, and my build command was `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_OPENMP=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_VTK=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON WITH_GTK_2_X=OFF -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -D WITH_NVCUVID=ON -D WITH_LAPACK=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/my/opencv_contrib/modules/path ..`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue but with another library file usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdcmMSFF.so.2.8: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
Look here for my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390133/unable-to-build-binary-for-target-dso-dataset-libgdcmmsff-so-2-8-undefined-refe).
I think you may also got a warning that files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

**Solution** in my case: I added /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in bashrc file and sourced it. Then, I have moved the libuuid library file under anaconda3/lib to anaconda3/libuuid. No more errors for me and I hope this could work as well.